# Python MySQL connection error when executed through Docker Container

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I am trying to execute this code below to update a SQL Table Column called "Extra_Time_Counter".

**Section from python file "twitter_app"**

```
# Create the database connection
db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host = "aws_database",
        user = "new_master_user",
        passwd = "***********",
        port = "3306",
        database = "testdb"
    )

mycursor = db.cursor()

query = "UPDATE twitter_fixtures_df SET Extra_Time_Counter = 0"
mycursor.execute(query)
db.commit()
print("All Extra Time Counters Set back to 0")
```

This is being executed in a **Docker Container** and causes this error below

```
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I have tested this locally by running the python file and there is no error!

**DockerFile**

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /application

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "./twitter_app.py"]
```

I am not using the root MySQL user (Different user with the same privilege's as the admin user).

Comment: what is `aws_database`? If your host knows how to get the IP of this alias, then you should also let the container know how to do that.

Comment: Sorry this is just a generic name that I put in to the mysql connector to the aws server! How would I do that?

Comment: I also don't know what is a "generic name". However, if you can ping `aws_database` from the host, then it means that the mapping is defined somewhere in the hosts file. If you can ping it, then you can see also the IP. So you can take that IP and use it in  your docker run command. Something like this: `docker run --add-host aws_database:<database_server_IP> ...`

Comment: Thank you for you help. The problem is that in the python "twitter_app" I run a query "mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")" and this is executed without any errors. So really not sure why the update query is causing an issue....